# Python linear prog. without using scipy.optimize.linprog OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I tried to implement this transportation problem directly without using the scipy.optmize.lineprog library :
(The Transportation Problem). Quantities a1, a2, . . . , a m, respectively,
of a certain product are to be shipped from each of m locations and received in
amounts b1, b2, . . . , b n, respectively, at each of n destinations. Associated with the
shipping of a unit of product from origin i to destination j is a shipping cost c i j. It is
desired to determine the amounts x i j to be shipped between each origin–destination
pair i = 1, 2, . . . , m; j = 1, 2, . . . , n; so as to satisfy the shipping requirements and
minimize the total cost of transportation.
pardon my english i'm from a french-speaking country

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Données du problème
m = 3  # Nombre d'origines
n = 4  # Nombre de destinations
a = np.array([20, 30, 25])  # Offres des origines
b = np.array([10, 15, 25, 15])  # Demandes des destinations
c = np.array([
    [5, 4, 7, 6],
    [8, 6, 9, 7],
    [6, 3, 4, 5]
])  # Coûts d'expédition

# Matrice des variables de décision (quantités à expédier)
x = np.zeros((m, n))

# Algorithme du transport initial
while np.sum(x) < np.sum(b):
    min_supply = np.min(a)
    min_demand = np.min(b)
    
    i, j = np.unravel_index(c.argmin(), c.shape)
    quantity = min(min_supply, min_demand)
    
    x[i, j] = quantity
    a[i] -= quantity
    b[j] -= quantity
    c[i,j]= np.inf

# Affichage de la solution
print("Solution optimale (quantités à expédier) :")
print(x)

# Affichage du graphique de la solution
plt.imshow(x, cmap='Blues', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("Quantités à expédier")
plt.xlabel("Destinations")
plt.ylabel("Origines")
plt.xticks(range(n), [f"Destination {i+1}" for i in range(n)])
plt.yticks(range(m), [f"Origine {i+1}" for i in range(m)])
plt.show()
```

this the occured error

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 29
     27     a[i] -= quantity
     28     b[j] -= quantity
---> 29     c[i,j]= np.inf
     31 # Affichage de la solution
     32 print("Solution optimale (quantités à expédier) :")

OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

Comment: What is the purpose of avoiding `linprog`?

Comment: you are trying to put a float value, `inf`, into an `int` dtype array!

Answer (score 0):

Use a large value to represent infinity-like condition like:

```
x[i, j] = quantity
a[i] -= quantity
b[j] -= quantity
c[i, j] = 9999999
```